# Image module : Horizontal mirror image

Tags: python, image, mirror

I have this assignment : Write a function that does a horizontal mirror image in `Python Image` module. I kinda did the code (not complete) but I still got an error:

> TypeError: unorderable types: Pixel() < int()

Help would be much appreciated thanks :D

```
for i in range(0,img.getHeight()):
    for j in range(0,int(img.getWidth()/2)):
        old_pixel = img.getPixel(i, j)
        a = old_pixel.getRed()
        b = old_pixel.getGreen()
        c = old_pixel.getBlue()
        new_pixel = image.Pixel(a, b, c)
        new_image.setPixel(new_pixel,img.getWidth()-1-i, j)
```

Comment: For your `for j in range(...` line, change your range as follows: `range(0,int(img.getWidth()/2))`

Comment: I suppose it's `(img.getWidth()/2)`. Try to add `int`: `int(img.getWidth()/2)`. If your width is odd, `old_pixel` will be a float.

Comment: Also, please provide a pointer to the line on which the error is thrown

Comment: Then I get this: TypeError: unorderable types: Pixel() < int()

Comment: Please accompany every error that you get along with the line at which the error is thrown. It makes it MUCH easier to debug the problem

Comment: Can you edit/update your question with the *full* traceback (copy-paste) please.

Comment: for i in range(0,img.getHeight()):
        for j in range(0,int(img.getWidth()/2)):
            old_pixel = img.getPixel(i, j)
            a = old_pixel.getRed()
            b = old_pixel.getGreen()
            c = old_pixel.getBlue()
            new_pixel = image.Pixel(a, b, c)
            new_image.setPixel(new_pixel,img.getWidth()-1-i, j)

Comment: You just copied the same code into a comment. Perhaps you meant to do the *traceback* instead, that is, the full error message. And please edit it into your question, not a comment.

Comment: done. Is it okay now?

Comment: No: the traceback is a set of lines showing the error, starting with "Traceback (most recent call last):" and ending with your actual "TypeError: unorderable types: Pixel() < int()". We'd like to see *all* of those lines, because some information in your question seems to be missing.

Comment: Also, we need more code. There does not seem to be `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods, so I wonder where they come from. You may want to show your full script instead.